# Universal .htaccess for angularjs that works with HTML5 route parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

Here is the .htaccess file I have currently:

```
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

It works for url's like this:

`http://domain.com/view`

`http://domain.com/otherview`

But if I try and do a hard refresh on parameters like this:

`http://domain.com/view/3523`

`http://domain.com/view/1234/5322`

If I do a hard refresh on any parameter generated pages it just shows index.html without any Javascript loaded, which breaks the page.

The parameter URL's work if I navigate to the page from within the app, otherwise they don't work.

How do I get parameter URL's to work on a hard refresh within AngularJS.

I also have HTML5 mode turned on:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Comment: after 3 hours research, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45234725/11797071 this answer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: That still has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the other post:
[AngularJS routes + .htacces rewriting + route Parameters = not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221918/angularjs-routes-htacces-rewriting-route-parameters-not-working)

You just need to put your base tag at the top of all tags. At least it worked for most of us.